# Проблема при верстке для DLE

Tags: вёрстка, css

Здраствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой верстки под dle. А именно файл comments.tpl 
[image]

Как можно убрать то, что обведено красным в самый низ? или же наоборот в самый верх?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Привет! Дамно работал с ДЛЕ. Чтобы дать ответ киньте исходники comments.tpl


Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день, вы знакомы с блочной вёрсткой?

**Добавлено.**

[Абсолютное позиционирование элемента внутри родительского](http://www.myfirstsite.ru/notes/absolutnoe-pozicionirovanie-elementa-vnutri-roditelskogo).

Comment: Да.

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не могу найти этот элемент, дабы убрать его.

Comment: Видите ли, элемент, ex."{registration}", подключает набор элементов как `include();` поэтому вам стоит пользоваться firebug, чтобы найти этот элемент и работать с его стилями. Где находятся внутренности этого элемента, сказать не могу, в силу своей упёртости в самописаные cms.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался. )